# Will inserting null or the string literal "null" into Oracle number datatype be sufficient to cause ORA-01401

Tags: sql, oracle

Will inserting null or the string literal "null" into Oracle number datatype be sufficient to cause ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting null will not cause it, but "null" may cause it if you e.g. have defined the column to be of `varchar(2)` as in this case the column has be defined to hold at most 2 characters.

[ Update ] I did miss the "number data type" in the question. In this case if you insert "null" you should get an error about it nor being a number.

Comment: hi Heiko, what if the column is of a number data type?

Comment: +1 Hi Heiko, thanks, i would've fired up my DB to check this, but i am currently off hands, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect that error when inserting the literal 'null', I would expect:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: For the string literal, but not for NULL